# Calculate Var(X) from E(X) from a IDD binary sequence?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

Consider an IID (independent and identically distributed) sequence of random variables denoting the result of Bernoulli trials $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$, $X_n$, where each trial succeeds with a probability $p$.

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of successes obtained. Alternatively, if we consider the success of a Bernoulli trial to be expressed as the value $1$ and its failure as the value $0$, we can define $X$ as the sum of the random variables in the sequence: $X = \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i$.

We know that there are formulae for calculating $Var[X]$ from $E[X]$,
$Var[X] = E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.

We are given $E[X] = np$ and $Var[X]= np(1-p)$.

Can someone please show how to derive $Var[X]= np(1-p)$?

Attempted $E[X^2]$ = $np^2$, then $E^2[X]=(?)^2$ .

Comment: What do you mean by binary sequence? Do you mean that $X$ is Bernoulli distributed? Note that in this case $X^2=X$ so $E[X^2]=E[X]$. Or do you mean $X$ is binomially distributed with some parameters $n$ and $p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more handsome to go for the variance directly (so without calculation of $\mathbb EX$).

Apply:$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf{Covar}(X,X)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathsf{Covar}(X_i,X_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{Covar}(X_i,X_i)=n\mathsf{Covar}(X_1,X_1)=n\mathsf{Var}(X_1)$$where the second equality rests on bilinearity of covariance, the third on independence and the fourth on symmetry.

Comment: Thanks @drhab. So in this case, $X_{1}$ is the covar($X_{1},X_{1}$), which Var(X). but how can we just turn $X_{j}$ into $X_{i}$ first?

Comment: I do not turn $X_i$ into  $X_j$ but observe that $\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$ because then $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent. So all terms $\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ with $i\neq j$ can be left out and the remaining sum is $\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{Covar}(X_i,X_i)$.